# React textarea component not able to expand horizontally

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React/JS and I am on a spot where I want to have a textarea that I can resize horizontally and vertically. I have tried using react-bootstrap text area and one from material-ui (https://material-ui.com/components/textarea-autosize/).

My app.js looks like this..

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
     <TextareaAutosize />
    </div>
  )
}
```

But when the text area is spawned on the page I can only expand the text area up and down and not wider.

Comment: Because it does not mean to expand the width? Why do you need to resize the width?

Comment: As I can see, the textarea width it limited by the parent class. Did you try tro increase the width of TextareaAutosize parent tag (means the div after `return (`)?

Comment: The parent div has no width size. I can change the size by cols but I want it resizeable with the mouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textarea element from that library only helps with adjusting the height, not the width.

I played around with it in Code Sandbox and figured out that you can manually set the width by adding a `cols` property and setting it to a number like this:

```
<TextareaAutosize
   aria-label="minimum height"
   rowsMin={3}
   placeholder="Minimum 3 rows"
   cols={50}
/>
```

Check out [the Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3hnb7) I created.

Comment: Yeah I know that is possible. But why can I resize the textarea with my mouse on that example but not on mine? That is my issue. I am probably going to just accept that it won't work for me and only allow a vertical resize.

Comment: Yeah, I see that you can click and drag the example and make it wider but there's no width adjusting property in the API. I think you'll have to set the columns statically.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the inbuilt textarea property in html
2. In Css use textarea{ resize:both  }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).